# Can an abelian group be isomorphic to the quotient of two of its subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

#### First problem

Suppose that $A$, $B$, $C$ are infinite abelian groups such that $C < B < A$ (where with the symbol "<" I mean "proper subgroup").
Is it possible that $$A \simeq \frac{B}{C}?$$

#### Second problem

Let $E$ be an abelian group, and $d\colon E \to E$ a non-null group morphism such that $d^2 = 0$. Is it possible that $$E \simeq \frac{\ker{d}}{\operatorname{Im}(d)}?$$

Context:
When I asked for these problems, I was studying from Bott-Tu's book "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" some chapters about spectral sequences in filtered complexes, in double complexes and on fiber bundles (pag.160-172). In order to clarify some things, I asked myself what was the conditions needed for a spectral sequence to reach a stable value. Of course, if there is a natural $r$ such that the differentials after $r$ are all null, the sequence stabilizes. Is it true also the converse?
Thanks to the answer to this topic, the converse is proved to be not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: yes. Let $A$ be the free abelian group on $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...\}$, $B$ the subgroup generated by $\{x_2,x_4,x_6,x_8,...\}$ and $C$ the subgroup generated by $\{x_4, x_8,...\}$. Then  all groups $A$, $B$, $C$, $B/C$ are free abelian groups of countable rank and hence are isomorphic.

Second question: yes. Consider the morphism $A\to A$ determined by the map:
$x_1\to x_2,x_2\to 0, x_3\to 0; x_4\to x_5, x_5\to 0, x_6\to 0; x_7\to x_8, x_8\to 0, x_9\to 0;...$ and so on. Then $Im=\left<x_2,x_5,x_8,...\right>$, $Ker=\left<x_2,x_3,x_5,x_6,x_8,x_9,...\right>$ and $Ker/Im\cong\left<x_3,x_6,x_9,...\right>$ which is again free abelian of countably infinite rank.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the group of maps $f\colon\mathbb N_0\to\mathbb Z$ (under pointwise addition). Let $B$ be the subgroup of $f$ with $f(0)=0$. Let $C$ be the subgroup with $f(n)=0$ for all even $n$. Then $B\to A$, $f\mapsto\left(n\mapsto f(2n+1)\right)$ is onto and has $C$ as kernel.

Comment: Thank you Mr. von Eitzen, very nice example (+1).
However, I accepted the answer from @user59363 because it is more complete.